# Creating two filled plots that overlap with transparency

Tags: pgfplots, transparency

I'm using `pgfplots` to plot two filled curves. I'd like them to overlap transparently so that the "lower" figure can be seen through the "upper one". Using the `forget style` mode will draw the first figure transparently, but that's the one that is below !

MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar,bar width=2pt]
  \addplot[color=red,mark=,draw=red,fill opacity=0.5] table[x=0,y=1]\transtable;
  \addplot[color=blue,mark=,draw=blue,fill opacity=0.5] table[x=2,y=3]\transtable;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a direct way to get somewhat transparent overlapping plots ?

Comment: add `fill opacity=0.5` to the `addplot` command and please include a simple MWE which in this case 6-7 lines long so easier than typing out the question :).

Comment: The problem with what you recommend is that it doesn't appear to work for bar charts.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem. I need to use `draw opacity` instead of `fill opacity`. Not sure whether I should delete the question. Ideally @percusse can post an answer and I'll accept it, since that's what got me on the right track.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `fill opacity` key to change the ...hmm... fill opacity.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
  \addplot[red,no marks,fill] {x} \closedcycle;
  \addplot[no marks,fill,blue,fill opacity=0.2,samples=100] {10*sin(x*20*pi)} \closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]